# Calculate joint pdf from joint cdf

Tags: probability

> The number of minor surgeries, X, and the number of major surgeries,
>   Y, for a policyholder, this decade, has joint cumulative distribution
>   function $F (x, y) = [1 − (0.5)^{x+1}][1 − (0.2)^{y+1}]$ for non-negative
>   integers x and y. Calculate the probability that the policyholder
>   experiences exactly three minor surgeries and exactly three major
>   surgeries this decade.

**Correct answer = .004**

My solution : Take derivative with respect to $dx, dy$ of given join cdf gives us joint pdf, then simply plug in x=3, y=3? I am getting $ln(.5)(.5)^xln(.2)(.2)^y  (.2)(.5) = .000011$

Comment: Please could you give more information? What are the possible values of $x$ and $y$? Besides, it seems you can cancel $+1$ and $-1$ in the formula and get to $F(x,y) = (0.5)x \cdot (0.2)y = 0.1 x y$

Comment: What does [1-(0.5)x+1] mean? Does it mean $2-0.5x$ or $1-0.5(x+1)$?

Comment: Taking derivatives doesn't work in this case because $x$ and $y$ are discrete.  I   think that the answer should be  $F(3,3)+F(2,2)-F(3,2)-F(2,3)$ (hint: inclusion-exclusion principle), but this doesn't work out to $.004$.

Comment: @AngelaRichardson from the attempted derivation it seem to mean $[1-0.5^{x+1}]$.  But, indeed, there is no pdf to derive since the distribution is discrete.

Comment: ...and infact using your method with that interpretation gives $\approx0.004$ .

Comment: Yup @AngelaRichardson that's the right answer! thank you!